# Заменить нулями повторяющиеся элементы в списке (если их несколько, заменить только последний)

Tags: python, алгоритм, python-3.x

```
from random import randint

list1 = []

for i in range(20):
    list1.append(randint(-10, 10))
```

На входе:

```
list1 = [9, -3, -5, 5, 3, 6, -6, 9, 5, 0, 7, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5, 8, 9, 7]
```

На выходе:

```
list1 = [9, -3, -5, 5, 3, 6, -6, 9, 5, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 0]
```

Comment: так все повторы занулить, или только последний из них? повторы подряд или в принципе? пример того, что на входе и на выходе в итоге?

Comment: На входе: list1 = [9, -3, -5, 5, 3, 6, -6, 9, 5, 0, 7, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5, 8, 9, 7]         На выходе: list1 = [9, -3, -5, 5, 3, 6 , 9, 5, 0, 7, 4, 0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 0]

Comment: @Михаил, пример правильный? на выходе элементов меньше стало

Answer (score 6):

Можно так, совсем по-простому (линейный алгоритм):

```
index_dict = {}

for index_num, item in enumerate(list1):  # нумерованный список
    if item in index_dict:
        index_dict[item] = index_num  # присваиваем последний индекс
    else:
        index_dict[item] = -1  # присваиваем не существующий индекс

del_list = [index_dict[item] for i in index_dict if index_dict[item] > -1]  # выражение-генератор с условием

for i in del_list:
    list1[i] = 0
```

Написал на вскидку, если списки не очень большие, можно так, если большие, надо продумывать и экономить.

Comment: for n, i in enumerate(list1):  , del_list = [d[i] for i in d if d[i] > -1]v                                                                                    Что значат эта записи?

Comment: Для индекса и эл-та в нумерованном списке, читайте доки

Comment: @Михаил я добавил коменты в код, читайте что это и разбирайтесь, мой пример работает, проверял

Comment: Спасибо! Я тоже проверил.)

Comment: `enumerate` первым элементом пары дает индекс, а вторым сам элемент. Плюс, первоначальный список заполняется как положительными, так и отрицательными элементами. Насколько я вижу, у вас наличие отрицательных элементов не учитывается.

Comment: @insolor все учитываеться, более того, эл-т списка может быть не только число, а в принципе любой объект, я записываю в словарь именно индекс эл-та и изменяю список по индексу последнего эл-та

Comment: @IgorSergeevich, вот теперь я действительно понял ваш ответ, когда итеративно доупростил свой второй вариант, получилось практически то же что у вас)

Comment: @insolor хорошо ;)

Comment: @jfs нет, была свободная минутка и написал по-бымтрому, имена сейчас поправлю

Answer (score 3):

## Вариант 1 (линейная сложность):

Делаем проход по циклу, чтобы получить индексы, когда в последний раз встретился каждый элемент. Если элемент встретился впервые, то записываем для него не индекс, а `None`. Для последующих появлений элемента уже записываем его индекс. Если элемент встретится несколько раз, то в словарь в итоге в словарь будет записан индекс последнего вхождения элемента (или `None`, если элемент элемент встретился только один раз).

Вторым циклом просто записываем нули в список для тех элементов из словаря, для которых указан индекс, а не `None` (т.е. которые встретились более одного раза).

```
last_encounters = {}
for i, item in enumerate(list1):
    if item not in last_encounters:
        last_encounters[item] = None
    else:
        last_encounters[item] = i

for i in last_encounters.values():
    if i is not None:
        list1[i] = 0
```

Собственно, все свелось к варианту от **Igor Sergeevich**, первоначально у меня словарей было два, причем заполнялись они двумя отдельными циклами.

## Вариант 2 (квадратичная сложность):

Этот вариант оставляю в ответе, возможно он будет более понятен для новичков, но он менее оптимален, чем вариант выше.

Два вложенных цикла, один цикл с начала до конца списка, второй - с конца до текущего элемента (не включая его). Если во вложенном цикле попадается элемент, совпадающий с текущим, заменяем нулем, выходим из цикла. Если какое-то значение уже занулили, добавляем его в `set()`, и если в списке еще раз попадется, то не зануляем.

```
nulled = set()
for i, item in enumerate(list1):
    if item not in nulled:
        for j in range(len(list1)-1, i, -1):
            if item == list1[j]:
                nulled.add(item)
                list1[j] = 0
                break
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял автора (квадратичный алгоритм):

```
items = [9, -3, -5, 5, 3, 6, -6, 9, 5, 0, 7, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5, 8, 9, 7, 10]
print(items)

# Для поиска списка дубликатов
from collections import Counter
duplicate_list = [x for x, count in Counter(items).items() if count > 1]
#
# OR:
# duplicate_list = list(dict(filter(lambda x: x[1] > 1, Counter(items).items())).keys())

new_items = []

# Перебор элементов в обратном порядке
for x in reversed(items):
    # Если элемент есть в списке дубликатов
    if x in duplicate_list:
        duplicate_list.remove(x)
        x = 0

    new_items.append(x)

# Возвращаем нормальный порядок
new_items.reverse()
print(new_items)
```

Консоль:

```
[9, -3, -5, 5, 3, 6, -6, 9, 5, 0, 7, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5, 8, 9, 7, 10]
[9, -3, -5, 5, 3, 6, -6, 9, 5, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 0, 10]
```

Comment: Хотят только последний заменять на нуль

Comment: На входе: list1 = [9, -3, -5, 5, 3, 6, -6, 9, 5, 0, 7, 6, 4, 4, 5, 5, 8, 9, 7,10] На выходе: list1 = [9, -3, -5, 5, 3, 6, -6, 9, 5, 0, 7, 4, 0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 0,10]

Comment: @Михаил, подправил, а теперь?

Comment: Как-то много писанины. Попробуйте упростить.

Comment: @0andriy, наверное много. Но много писанины в сравнении с чем?

Comment: Я тоже думал использовать реверс, но мне кажется проблема не столько в решении, сколько в постановке задачи, наверное тут проще создать свой пользовательский список с условием на повторение и решать вопрос при генерации списка или добавлении эл-тов

Comment: @jfs, квадратичная из-за `if x in duplicate_list`? Потом что нужно делать поиск в другом цикле? А если бы там был не список, а словарь?

Comment: да и .remove(x) также O(n) для списков в Питоне

Comment: @jfs, а словари обеспечивают O(1) для получения и удаления?

Comment: да (амортизировано)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы заменить нулем последнее появление повторяющегося элемента в списке,  можно обходить список в обратном порядке, запоминая индексы встреченных элементов, и если они встречаются повторно, то обнулить их значение по сохранённому самому правому индексу:

```
def zero_last_nonuniq(items):
    seen = {}
    for i in range(len(items) - 1, -1, -1):
        value = items[i]
        if value in seen:  # already seen, non-uniq value
            items[seen[value]] = 0  # set to zero the right-most occurence
        else:  # first time
            seen[value] = i  # save the right-most index
```

Пример:

```
>>> values = [1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 2, 1, 4, 4, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5, 4]
>>> zero_last_nonuniq(values)
>>> values == [1, 1, 2, 1, 5, 4, 5, 4, 4, 5, 0, 1, 4, 4, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0]
True
```

Это однопроходной вариант уже представленного в других ответах линейного алгоритма, использующего `seen` словарь, чтобы отслеживать уже встреченные элементы:

```
import random

values = [random.randint(-10, 10) for _ in range(20)]

seen = {}
for index, value in enumerate(values):
    if value in seen:  # already seen, non-uniq value
        seen[value] = index  # override the last seen index
    else: # first time
        seen[value] = None

for index in seen.values():
     if index is not None: # last index of a non-uniq value
         values[index] = 0
# -> [9, -3, -5, 5, 3, 6, -6, 9, 5, 0, 7, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 8, 0, 0]
```

По сути используется та же идея, что и [в ответе Igor Sergeevich](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/711399/23044), а реализация (независимо) получилась идентичной решению из [@insolor ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/711942/23044).

Comment: У меня в последней редакции практически один в один как у вас)

Comment: @insolor: добавил однопроходной вариант.