# Неисправность кода Python. Проблема описана снизу

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from random import randint

list1 = []

for i in range(20):
 list1.append(randint(-10, 10))
```

Вот код для нахождения парных элементов в списке, и удаления последних из них:

```
for povt1 in list1:
 for povt2 in range(1,len(list1)):
  if list1[povt2] == povt1:
   idx = povt2
  else:
   povt2 += 1
  if list1[povt2] == idx:
   list1[povt2] = 0
   povt1 += 1
```

Кто подскажет, что с ним не так и почему он не работает?

Вот ошибка:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "main.py", line 56, in <module>
    if list1[povt2] != idx:
 IndexError: list index out of range
exited with non-zero status
```

Что на входе:

`[9, -6, 5, 8, 10, -1, 9, -2, -8, 9, -6, 9, -8, -2, -1, 0, 3, 2, 8, 8]`

Что должно быть на выходе:

`[9, -6, 5, 8, 10, -1, 9, -2, -8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 8, 0]`

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: list1.append(randint(-10, 10")) что то там не то.

Comment: Нужно прикладывать стек ошибки к вопросу, а то сразу непонятно: алгоритм неправильный или синтаксис

Comment: Михаил Алексеевич, это ошибка при копировании кода, в самом коде ковычек нет

Comment: @Михаил в примере требуемого вывода где-то элемент потерялся.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/711386/1365

Comment: @insolor это тоже задавал я, но сейчас я написал какое-никакое решение, но в не есть ошибка, вот я и спросил о том, что не так

Comment: @Михаил, да я знаю. Просто добавил комментарий, чтобы тот вопрос справа отображался в связанных.

Comment: Как то вы интересно индекс элемента берёте... :)

Comment: @МихаилАлексеевич у вас есть идеи почему код не работает?

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно элементам которые повторяются присвоить 0? Задача как-то не очень хорошо описана, не совсем понятно что нужно делать...

Comment: @АндрейМоскаленко только последним элементам из повторяющихся присвоить ноль.                                                               
                                                                                                               Что на входе:

    [9, -6, 5, 8, 10, -1, 9, -2, -8, 9, -6, 9, -8, -2, -1, 0, 3, 2, 8, 8]

Что должно быть на выходе:

    [9, -6, 5, 8, 10, -1, 9, -2, -8, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 8, 0]

Answer (score 0):

Падение у вас из-за выхода за пределы массива после строки `povt2 += 1`, после прибавки сразу же использование без проверки.

Переписал вот так (на выходе `list2`):

```
from random import randint

list1 = []

for i in range(20):
    list1.append(randint(-10, 10))
list2 = list1[:]

for i in range(0,len(list1)):
    idx = 0
    for j in range(i+1,len(list1)):
        if list1[i] == list1[j]:
            idx = j
    if idx:
        list2[idx] = 0
```

Comment: Спасибо! А что значат строчки: list2 = list[:], if idx:

Comment: list2 = list[:] это создание копии

Comment: if idx: равнозначно if idx != 0:

Comment: у вас немного не то... у вас удаляются все повторы кроме первого, а надо чтобы удалялся только последний повтор

Comment: Как раз только последний и удаляется

Comment: вот что я получаю                                                                             
[9, -9, 3, 1, -7, -3, 4, -9, -6, -9, 7, -3, 7, -7, 7, 2, -3, 9, 7, 6]                                                   

[9, -9, 3, 1, -7, -3, 4, 0, -6, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6]

Comment: приведите пример

Comment: list1 = [9, -9, 3, 1, -7, -3, 4, -9, -6, -9, 7, -3, 7, -7, 7, 2, -3, 9, 7, 6]
list2 = list1[:]

for i in range(0,len(list1)):
    idx = 0
    for j in range(i+1, len(list1)):
        if list1[i] == list1[j]:
            idx = j
    if idx != 0:
        list2[idx] = 0

print(list1)
print(list2)

На выходе:
[9, -9, 3, 1, -7, -3, 4, -9, -6, -9, 7, -3, 7, -7, 7, 2, -3, 9, 7, 6]
[9, -9, 3, 1, -7, -3, 4, -9, -6, 0, 7, -3, 7, 0, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6]

Comment: В комментариях всё страшно выглядит, вы копировали мой код или перенабирали? Возможно чтото не так перенабрали

Comment: извините. Вы правы.